How to show last page viewed after closing MAUI app with prism way?
I have a MAUI app in android and iOS, I want to when my app reopen can show last viewed page, instead of showing first page.
I want to know best way to achieve this with Prism MAUI framework.

Every time you go to a screen save the route to it in a SharedPreference and when your app starts, use that preference to start over
